# Identityserver4 and groups management

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

### Background

I have IdentityServer4 application managing my users.

I want to upgrade my application to support groups of users. Each user on my app can be part of zero or more groups. Each group has exactly one administrator that can manage it (add more users, delete users and so on).

### Question

IdentityServer4 helps the developer to solve this challenge? or identityserver4 is not dealing with groups of users (therefore I'll have to implement it from scratch)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer does not deal with how you manage/group your users, this you have to handle all by your self.

One option ca be to try to use https://www.identityserver.com/products/adminui or https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin

Alternatively, you connect your IdentityServer with an external user management system, like AzureAD or Auth0...